# clear map zoom and geometries of feature layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online-basemaps

i have selected feature(feature layer) from combobox and it zoom to the feature . now i want to clear combobox slection and map . and zoom map to its default zoom.

```
//combobox selection clear
    dijit.byId("A1").reset();
    dijit.byId("A2").reset();
    dijit.byId("A3").reset();
    dijit.byId("A4").reset();
    dijit.byId("A5").reset();

    //layer selection clear
     document.getElementById('A1_layer').clearSelection();
      document.getElementById('A2_layerC').clearSelection();
      document.getElementById('A3_layerC').clearSelection();
      document.getElementById('A4_layerC').clearSelection();
      document.getElementById('A5_layerC').clearSelection();



app = {
    zoomRow: function(id, which){

      var query = new Query();
      //var thePoly, theExtent;
      if(which == "Land"){
        query.where = "Name='" + (id).toString() + "'";
        console.info(query.where);
        query.returnGeometry = true;
        A1_layer.selectFeatures(query, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function (features) {
          thePoly = features[0].geometry;
          theExtent = thePoly.getExtent().expand(2); //Zoom out slightly from the polygon's extent
          map.setExtent(theExtent);
        });
        esriRequest({
          url: "http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/........",
          content:{
            f:'json'
          },
          handleAs:'json',
          callbackParamName:'callback',
          timeout:15000
        }).then(lang.hitch(this,function(response){
          var store2 = new Memory({data:[]});
          dijit.byId("A2").set('store',store2);
          var data = array.map(response.features,lang.hitch(this,function(feat, index){
            var name = feat.attributes.nam;
            var dataItem = {
              id:index,
              name:name
            };
            return dataItem;
          }));
          store2 = new Memory({data:data});
          dijit.byId("A2").set('store',store2);
          document.getElementById('A2').value = "Select Room";
        }));
      }
<input id="A1" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox" value="Select landing" onchange="app.zoomRow(document.getElementById('A1').value, 'Land');" data-dojo-props="maxHeight: 200" style="overflow:auto; width:200px; background-color: #E7FCCA "/ ><br></br>
  <input id="A2" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox" value="Select room onchange="app.zoomRow(document.getElementById('A2').value, 'Room');"style="overflow:auto; width:200px ;background-color: #E7FCCA" /> <br></br>
```

but i got error "Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined" at thePoly = features[0].geometry;

Comment: Can you please post a longer example (maybe a code sample on jsbin.com)? I'm having a hard time understanding what your "A1..." and "A1_layer" dom nodes are referring to.

Comment: A1 are the feature layers i have added to the map . A1 is a combobox which populated with feature layers attributes

Comment: i have added more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the error you can simply check the feature first, before getting the geometry.

```
A1_layer.selectFeatures(query, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function (features) {
        if(features && features[0] && features[0].geometry){
             thePoly = features[0].geometry;
             theExtent = thePoly.getExtent().expand(2); //Zoom out slightly from the polygon's extent
             map.setExtent(theExtent);
          }
        });
```

Hoping this will help you :)

Comment: Glad to help you once again... :)

Comment: as i mentioned it is cascading filtering. if i use if condition it does not zoom to the next feature in the combobox.